# Resizing QT's QTextEdit to Match Text Width

Tags: html, css, qt, qtextedit

I have a QMainWindow that has a QVBoxLayout with a QTextEdit inside. I use insertHtml to the latter with a fixed CSS that basically boils down to monospace lines with a constant width, so it should be predictable, once a line enters, how wide should be the QTextEdit to show the whole text. The problem is, I don't know how to get that width. I tried a lot of things: adjustSize(), getting the size of the underlying QTextDocument, QFontMetrics (does not measure an HTML that has a class modified by a stylesheet), even doing

```
QFont f("monospace");
QFontMetrics fm(f);
QString s = QString("A").repeated(MyTextWidth);
unsigned NewWidth = fm.width(s)
```

yields a value that applied to the QTextEdit with setFixedWidth gives an incorrect result.
So how can I do to set automatically the QTextEdit's width (and hence the QMainWindow's that owns it) to display the whole line of text without using horizontal scrollbars?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `QTextDocument::idealWidth` to determine real text width. It's important to make `QTextEdit` visible before querying ideal width. Don't forget to add content margins to its value.

```
QTextEdit textEdit;
textEdit.setHtml("<p>test test test test test test</p><p>|||||||||</p>");
textEdit.show();
textEdit.setFixedWidth(textEdit.document()->idealWidth() +
                       textEdit.contentsMargins().left() +
                       textEdit.contentsMargins().right());
```

Result:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Sounds really good, but it is not working on this side, it wraps the text of your example. Bear in mind this is my first experience with Qt. My complete code is: `class Test : public QMainWindow
{
public:
 Test(QWidget *parent = 0) : QMainWindow(parent)
 {
     QTextEdit *text = new QTextEdit();
     text->setReadOnly(true);
     text->insertHtml("<p>test test test test test test</p><p>|||||||||</p>");
     text->show();
  text->setFixedWidth(text->document()->idealWidth() +
                       text->contentsMargins().left() +
                       text->contentsMargins().right()); }
};`

Comment: I added a button with the `insertHTML()` and the `setFixedWidth()` calls, and everytime I add the HTML of your example, the QTextEdit shrinks a little more. Do I lack something in the layout setting, or in the QTextEdit itself?