How can I implement a responsive QPlainTextEdit?
Here's an MRE:
import sys, random
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        main_splitter = MainSplitter(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(main_splitter)
        main_splitter.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        main_splitter.setStyleSheet('background-color: red; border: 1px solid pink;');
        
        # top component of vertical splitter: a QFrame to hold horizontal splitter and breadcrumbs QPlainTextEdit
        top_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        top_frame_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        top_frame.setLayout(top_frame_layout)
        top_frame.setStyleSheet('background-color: green; border: 1px solid green;');
        main_splitter.addWidget(top_frame)
        
        # top component of top_frame: horizontal splitter
        h_splitter = HorizontalSplitter()
        h_splitter.setStyleSheet('background-color: cyan; border: 1px solid orange;')
        top_frame_layout.addWidget(h_splitter)

        # bottom component of top_frame: QPlainTextEdit (for "breadcrumbs")
        self.breadcrumbs_pte = BreadcrumbsPTE(top_frame)
        top_frame_layout.addWidget(self.breadcrumbs_pte)
        self.text = 'some plain text '
        self.breadcrumbs_pte.setPlainText(self.text * 50)
        self.breadcrumbs_pte.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
        self.breadcrumbs_pte.setStyleSheet('background-color: orange; border: 1px solid blue;');
        self.breadcrumbs_pte.setMinimumWidth(300)
        self.breadcrumbs_pte.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)

        # bottom component of vertical splitter: a QFrame
        bottom_panel = BottomPanel(main_splitter)
        bottom_panel.setStyleSheet('background-color: magenta; border: 1px solid cyan;')
        main_splitter.addWidget(bottom_panel)

    def resizeEvent(self, *args):
        print('resize event...')
        n_repeat = random.randint(10, 50)
        self.breadcrumbs_pte.setPlainText(self.text * n_repeat)
        super().resizeEvent(*args)

class BreadcrumbsPTE(QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit):
    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(500, 100)

class MainSplitter(QtWidgets.QSplitter):
    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(40, 150)

class HorizontalSplitter(QtWidgets.QSplitter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)

        self.left_panel = LeftPanel()
        self.left_panel.setStyleSheet('background-color: yellow; border: 1px solid black;');
        self.addWidget(self.left_panel)
        self.left_panel.setMinimumHeight(150)

        right_panel = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        right_panel.setStyleSheet('background-color: black; border: 1px solid blue;');
        self.addWidget(right_panel)

        # to achieve 66%-33% widths ratio
        self.setStretchFactor(0, 20)
        self.setStretchFactor(1, 10)
         
    def sizeHint(self):
        return self.left_panel.sizeHint()
    
class LeftPanel(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(150, 250)

class BottomPanel(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(30, 180)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()

If you run it, you'll see that if you adjust the size of the window the text in the QPlainTextEdit changes each time.
What I'm trying to achieve: I want the text in the QPlainTextEdit to adjust the size of that component and the component above it (HorizontalSplitter) so that the QPlainTextEdit just contains perfectly the text, not leaving space at the bottom.
I want that to happen so that no adjustment to the size of the main window occurs (obviously if this happened, this would, as the code is written, currently lead to infinite triggering of the MainWindow.resizeEvent()).
The tutorials on Qt/PyQt just don't seem to give a comprehensive technical explanation of how all the various mechanisms work and how they interact. For example, I know that sizeHint plays a crucial role relating to sizing and layouts, but, short of trying to examine the source code in depth, I don't know how I can improve my understanding.
For example, I tried infinite permutations of commenting out sizeHint on the various classes here, including commenting them all out: but self.top_pte.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents) never seems to work (i.e. as I want it to!).
NB if necessary, BottomPanel (i.e. 2nd child of the vertical QSplitter) can be set with minimum and maximum height (i.e. fixed height) to make things simpler. The main aim is to get the horizontal QSplitter and the QPlainTextEdit to adjust so that the latter's height is just perfectly adjusted for the text it contains...

There's no comprehensive explanation because every layout is different, some widgets are quite complex and behave slightly differently than others, so it's actually impossible to provide a generic guide. Now, the first problem raises in how dynamically this should work: is the text length fixed/hardcoded? Does it change at runtime for the same widget? Or it's defined upon widget initialization, remaining the same until it's destroyed? Note that the size adjust policy is only respected by scroll areas that properly implement viewportSizeHint(): QScrollArea and QAbstractItemView subclasses.

The above is quite logical: 1. text has no specific layout, since its geometry may depend on the available width and the wrap mode; 2. text content is highly dynamical by nature, and implementing a properly adjusted size hint that may change every time even a single character changes in the text may be very demanding (the fact that the text edit may be read only is irrelevant). Then, there's another problem: if window resizing is possible, the parent would change the possible hint in very different ways, depending on the text, and possibly forcing the scroll bars to show or hide, therefore »

» causing possible recursion (even infinite, in very specific cases). This is why for situations like these it's normally preferred to always display the scroll bars (unless transient scroll bars are available, but they also have their drawbacks), even if they're not necessary because there's nothing to scroll. Please clarify what asked in my first comment and consider everything else I wrote.

Thanks, helpful explanations as ever. The text length keeps changing, which is why the MRE as implemented would, if a solution can be found, solve the problem in my app. In fact the TopLeftPanel contains a QTreeView, and the QPlainTextEdit will contain a "breadcrumbs" string showing the texts of the ancestor QStandardItems leading to the current one. Thus this will change each time the current index changes. In light of your comments I'm now assuming it will take code to accomplish what I want, maybe a signal, etc.

Come to think of it, it might be better to have the "breadcrumbs" under the TopSplitter to make things less irritating for the users: that way, when they select a new QStandardItem, and the breadcrumbs changes, at least the QStandardItem won't change position. In this case the height of the TopSplitter still needs to change. (Something might be nibbled off the bottom ... but that can be catered for by a "scroll-to-visible" on the QStandardItem).

Changed ... also, in light of your comments, incorporating "always on" for the QPlainTextEdit vertical scrollbar. But in fact I think the V scrollbar should never appear, if the height is properly adjusted.

NB this answer looks interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21467596/595305 ... will be working on that approach

I found an answer after several hours of experimenting. I don't know whether some of these techniques might be considered controversial (or just bad). If musicamante takes a look at this I'd be interested in your view.
import sys, random
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        main_splitter = MainSplitter(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(main_splitter)
        main_splitter.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        main_splitter.setStyleSheet('background-color: red; border: 1px solid pink;');
        
        # top component of vertical splitter: a QFrame to hold horizontal splitter and breadcrumbs QPlainTextEdit
        top_frame = TopFrame(self)
        top_frame_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        top_frame.setLayout(top_frame_layout)
        top_frame.setStyleSheet('background-color: green; border: 1px solid green;');
        main_splitter.addWidget(top_frame)
        
        # top component of top_frame: horizontal splitter
        h_splitter = HorizontalSplitter()
        h_splitter.setStyleSheet('background-color: cyan; border: 1px solid orange;')
        top_frame_layout.addWidget(h_splitter, stretch=1)

        # bottom component of top_frame: QPlainTextEdit (for "breadcrumbs")
        self.breadcrumbs_pte = BreadcrumbsPTE(top_frame)
        top_frame_layout.addWidget(self.breadcrumbs_pte)
        self.text = 'some plain text '
        self.breadcrumbs_pte.setPlainText(self.text * 50 + '... END')
        self.breadcrumbs_pte.setStyleSheet('background-color: orange; border: 1px solid blue;');
        self.breadcrumbs_pte.setMinimumWidth(300)

        # bottom component of vertical splitter: a QFrame
        bottom_panel = BottomPanel(main_splitter)
        bottom_panel.setStyleSheet('background-color: magenta; border: 1px solid cyan;')
        main_splitter.addWidget(bottom_panel)

    def resizeEvent(self, *args):
        print('WINDOW resize event...')
        n_repeat = random.randint(10, 50)
        self.breadcrumbs_pte.setPlainText(self.text * n_repeat + '... END')
        super().resizeEvent(*args)
        self.breadcrumbs_pte.resizeEvent(*args)

class TopFrame(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    pass

class BreadcrumbsPTE(QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        # print(f'+++ self.wordWrapMode() {self.wordWrapMode()}') # 4 (QTextOption::WrapAtWordBoundaryOrAnywhere)

    def resizeEvent(self, *args):
        print('BPTE resize event...')
        plain_text = self.document().toPlainText()
        print(f'+++ RESIZE len(plain_text) {len(plain_text)}')
        super().resizeEvent(*args)
        # fortunately it seemed possible to avoid this sort of technique:
        # QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.updateGeometry)
        self.updateGeometry()

    def sizeHint(self):
        super_hint = super().sizeHint()
        actual_size = self.size()
        print(f'+++ super_hint {super_hint} actual_size {actual_size}') # 
        document = QtGui.QTextDocument()
        plain_text = self.document().toPlainText()
        # print(f'+++ len(plain_text) {len(plain_text)}')
        document.setPlainText(plain_text)
        document.setTextWidth(float(actual_size.width()))
        document_float_size = document.size()
        document_int_size = QtCore.QSize(int(document_float_size.width()), int(document_float_size.height()))
        # print(f'+++ document_int_size {document_int_size}')
        self.updateGeometry()
        return document_int_size

    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        return self.sizeHint()


class MainSplitter(QtWidgets.QSplitter):
    pass

class HorizontalSplitter(QtWidgets.QSplitter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)

        self.left_panel = LeftPanel()
        self.left_panel.setStyleSheet('background-color: yellow; border: 1px solid black;');
        self.addWidget(self.left_panel)
        self.left_panel.setMinimumHeight(150)

        right_panel = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        right_panel.setStyleSheet('background-color: black; border: 1px solid blue;');
        self.addWidget(right_panel)

        # to achieve 66%-33% widths ratio
        self.setStretchFactor(0, 20)
        self.setStretchFactor(1, 10)
         
    def sizeHint(self):
        return self.left_panel.sizeHint()

class LeftPanel(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(150, 500)

class BottomPanel(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(30, 180)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()

I noticed that you could quite often get a main window resize event with nothing else (e.g. sizeHint on other components) happening ... so thought the best thing to do was to relay this resizeEvent directly on to the BreadcrumbsPTE. I don't know whether there's a better way of forcing the descendant widgets to trigger resizeEvent. Later yes, PTE has a signal textChanged ...
sizeHint triggers updateGeometry, and minimumSizeHint obviously just runs sizeHint, so it does that too. But BreadcrumbsPTE.resizeEvent also seems to need to trigger updateGeometry for things to work.
I was puzzled by the QTextDocument delivered by BreadcrumbsPTE.document in BreadcrumbsPTE.sizeHint: I couldn't seem to get this to change size: maybe it's constrained by its parent (or container), i.e. the BreadcrumbsPTE: for that reason I seemed to have to make a separate QTextDocument fill it with the text and set its width ... in order for it to tell me what the height of the wrapped text would then be...

For starters, I'd avoid to change the text on resizeEvent(), as it can cause some level of recursion that would make debugging quite difficult, especially if using opaque resizing. Eventually consider using a QTimer with a reasonable interval, possibly restarted within resizeEvent(), so that you can properly see the result in the current state of things. This is quite important: some widgets cause more than one resize event, sometimes using posted events to avoid recursion. The result is that the layout manager may trigger a further layout update after all widgets have been resized.

Other notes: sizeHint() should not call updateGeometry(), since it's updateGeometry() that normally causes calls to sizeHint() from the layout manager(s). This is, indirectly, the reason for which it's almost impossible to get a widget (or even a window) to always have a specific aspect ratio when using layout managers and other widgets with variable sizes, and it's also why there are known issues with word-wrap QLabels in certain layouts. As annoying as it may result (and other approaches may allow that), that's how Qt layouts work.

Considering the behavior of layout managers and some complex widgets (specifically, scroll areas) properly achieving this in a 100% reliable and efficient way may be somehow impossible: even if we "cached" some resize event and use it for proper delayed computation of a possible size hint, there will always be some important level of uncertainty about: 1. what caused the resizing; 2. how/when the resizing and sizeHint() calls may be done. In any case, one way of approaching this is by also considering hasHeightForWidth() and the related heightForWidth() function, but be aware: that may »

» still not be enough. The inner QAbstractTextDocumentLayout (which is QPlainTextDocumentLayout for QPlainTextEdit) may delay its layout computation on its own, and give you unexpected results because of the results of the implemented resizeEvent(). You could create a clone of the document, and set an appropriate layout for it, but then you shall always do that, including computing the whole layout (block by block, line by line) at every resize and size hint call. It may work, but you need to know the whole QTextDocument interface enough in order to do it reliably and efficiently.

Thanks. Great insights and explanations. Ever thought of writing a book on Qt?

You're welcome. Yes, I considered it, but I decided I'm not interested in it (it would take a lot of time and efforts to make a whole book, properly written and organized) and I doubt I'll ever change idea. Yet, I've had intended to create a small website, collecting some of my codes and tricks, some tutorials or recollections of my experiences, including revised/expanded versions of some answers I've given here on SO in the years. It would also take some time, but it may be more feasible. We'll see :-)
